# Sign of distance/arm when finding moment/torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, definition, torque, statics, moment

I know that $M=Fd$, but when I have a negative moment, does the sign of the moment matter when I'm calculating for distance? If yes, then what would it mean when distance is negative?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it as an exterior product:
$$\vec{M}=\vec{d}\times \vec{F}$$
Now let's assume $\vec{d}$ and $\vec{F}$ lie in $xy$ plane. Then $\vec{M}$ will be along the $z-$axis, either $\hat{z}$, or $-\hat{z}$. It depends on the relative situation of $\vec{d}$ and $\vec{F}$.

In elementary physics, sometimes, a moment in the direction of $̂$ is taken as a positive moment: $M>0$, while if it is in the direction of $-̂$, it is taken to be negative: $M<0$.

So sign of $\vec{M}$ is important because it determines the direction of $\vec{M}$.

Answer (score 0):

> does the sign of the moment matter when I'm calculating for distance?

No. See the figures below.

The distance $d$ is simply the magnitude of the position vector $\vec r$ between the point $o$ about which the moment is calculated and the point of application of the force. The moment about $o$ is given by the following vector cross product.

$$\vec M_{o}=\vec r x \vec F=dF\sin\theta$$

The direction of the force in the figure to the left causes a clockwise (negative) moment about $o$ in the z direction whereas the direction of the force vector in the figure to the right causes a counterclockwise (positive) moment about $o$.

The direction of the moment can also be shown by taking the right hand and pointing the index finger in the direction of $\vec r$ and the middle finger in the direction of $\vec F$. The thumb then points in the direction of $\vec M_o$.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The torque is:

$$\vec M=\vec d\times\vec F$$

assume

$$\vec d=d\,\left(\pm\vec e_x\right)\quad, \vec F=F\,\left(\pm\vec e_y\right)\quad, d>0~,F>0$$

you obtain

case I
$$\vec d=d\,\vec e_x~,\vec F=F\,\vec e_y\\
\vec M=d\,F\,\vec e_z$$

case II
$$\vec d=d\,\left(-\vec e_x\right)~,\vec F=F\,\vec e_y\\
\vec M=d\,F\,\left(-\vec e_z\right)$$

case III
$$\vec d=d\,\vec e_x~,\vec F=F\,\left(-\vec e_y\right)\\
\vec M=d\,F\,\left(-\vec e_z\right)$$

case IV
$$\vec d=d\,\left(-\vec e_x\right)~,\vec F=F\,\left(-\vec e_y\right)\\
\vec M=d\,F\,\vec e_z$$

thus the magnitude of the torque is always $~d\,F~$ and the direction is $~+\vec e_z~$ or $~-\vec e_z$